# keeping array consistency in URL when its a single element

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm sending query params in my Vue Router as per below example

```
this.$router.push({ 
  path: 'search', 
  query: { 
    something: anArray, 
  }
})
```

https://testurl.dev/#/search?something=1&something=2&something

In the above example, `something` is an `array`

https://testurl.dev/#/search?something=1

In the above example, the`something` is not an `array`

This becomes a pain handling it backend as its expecting to loop through an array, even if it contains one item.

What the best way around this?

Is there a way to have URLs constructed as `something[]=1`?

Comment: AFAIK there's currently no way to specify `something[]=1` with vue router. You could `JSON.stringify` the array and then decode it on the backend

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass query parameter as `something[]`:

```javascript
this.$router.push({
  path: 'search',
  query: {
    'something[]': anArray
  }
})
```

This way it will be passed as `something[]=1` for `anArray = 1` and `something[]=1&something[]=2` for `anArray = [1, 2]`.

Comment: Do you have an example of this working? For me, the `[]` get escaped: `something%5B%5D=a&something%5B%5D=b`

Comment: It's normal if it's encoded, query parameters are supposed to be. (`decodeURIComponent('something%5B%5D=a&something%5B%5D=b')`). Check this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/5vn679o7vl, play with `anArray` in `Hello.vue`.

Comment: Huh, you're right! But it's not getting encoded in the url in your example and it is getting encoded in the url when I tried it in my webpack project. Not sure why

Comment: I get the same issue as @thanksd in that the URL showing up is `something%5B%5D`. The project is compiled with Webpack, could it be this?

Comment: I think this is because I am trying to print the url onto the page as a share link. Somewhere along the way the `[]` characters are being escaped. Currently I'm doing `<span v-html="shareable_link"></span>` to display the link

Comment: I think its actually the `this.$router.resolve` which I am using to get a displayable URL that is causing the issue.